# How to log Darts NBEATS model in mlflow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, time-series, mlflow

I am using NBEATS algorithm of the Darts library to build the model. as it is built using Pytorch i am using mlflow.pytorch.log to try and log the model but i face the following error

TypeError: Argument 'pytorch_model' should be a torch.nn.Module.

```
torch.save(model,"model.pt")
mlflow.pytorch.log_model(model,"model.pt")
```

and face the following error.

TypeError: Argument 'pytorch_model' should be a torch.nn.Module.

I want to log the NBEATS model in mlflow and want to call it to make predictions